# JS: How to prevent form being submited several times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit

Simple form without validation. I don't want form being submited more than one time if user pushes submit button several times (i.e. due internet lag, or something else). I'm interested in a client side solution. jQuery or simple JavaScript are acceptable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the submit button:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled', true).text("Please wait...");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled'); 
});
```